Dynamically update cell reference

I currently have a formula in column A to automatically assign sequence numbers, to all added or deleted rows. Is it possible to conditionally format, or create a dropdown list in column C, to automatically update, if the cell id being referenced in column A changes?
The goal is to avoid using =$A*.


One option might be VBA, specifically the Worksheet.Calculate event or maybe the Worksheet.Change event.
